# Java application server to use or not if my program has no user interface?

Tags: java

I'm doing a project, splitting the whole application into frontend and backend (skipping database part first) and use jms as frontend and backend communicating platform. Frontend will be web-based, so we write jsps and servlets, packaging as war and deploy to application server(oracle weblogic). But for backend, since it has no user interface (just pick message from jms, new a thread to do db operation using JPA and do business logics and send result to jms), should I use application server to run my code?

I've tried putting code into regular application server, wrapping backend thread starting code in servlet context listener, storing started thread into servlet context, and everything seems to be fine. Spring part seems to work too. Is this the right way?

If I choose not to use the servlet way, how should i package my code and deploy to application server? The entry point of the code will be what class?

Comment: Have you looked at [Web Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) yet?

Comment: Yes. But for the unreliability nature of Web Service, we choose jms and forget web service.

Comment: You can although use Karaf, Servicemix or Fuse ESB for your backend.

Comment: @white         you mean using the OSGi server? Our code is asked to run on weblogic.

Comment: Only for backend. You are free to use weblogic for frontend. These OSGI servers have builtin spring support, you can although install amq to server. [ESB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus) is supposed to be the best solution to expose services.

Comment: Even backend should be run on weblogic. There is something political. *shrug* Maybe I can persuade my boss to run our code at command line. But running on open source platform? My boss will be killed by his boss.

Comment: I thought the question is: 'To use AS or not?'. Anyway Fuse is owned by Red Hat and is enterprise system. Spring is open source, and what solution do you use for JMS transport? ActiveMQ f.ex. is OS too.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [**Spring components for handling JMS**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jms.html).

In short, you can define `JMS Listeners` and use `Message-Driven POJOs`. This is the simplest way I can think for a project which is already `using Spring`.

**EDIT:**

You can define you own start up class which will start on the start up of the server e.g. [**documentation for Weblogic Startup Class**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15586_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/startup_shutdown/ConfigureStartupAndShutdownClasses.html).

Comment: err, my problem is not about how to handle JMS. Although I'm using home-made code about JMS part, it works without problem. My problem is how to let the code start running.

Comment: That is what I tried answering. Since you wanted JMS based initiation, `I suggested to define listeners`. `Listener` will listen to the `JMS queue` and as soon as a message is receive, it will trigger the associated `Message-Driven POJO`, which can call your down layer components. Is not what are you asking?

Comment: I know defining JMS listener. But using this you must define a spring bean in spring config xml, leading to new ApplicationContext() to do the bean injection. But in a application server without web interface, who(or which class) is responsible for get this ApplicationContext()?

Comment: You can define you own start up class which will start on the start up of the server e.g. [**documentation for Weblogic Startup Class**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15586_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/startup_shutdown/ConfigureStartupAndShutdownClasses.html).

Comment: Ok, this is something i want. Will do some research.

Comment: All the best! Almost all the servers support this behavior. Please don't forget to accept the answer, if it was helpful.